# cant pass GeoDataClient in placeAutocomplete adapter?

Tags: java, google-places

I am trying to make a google place autocomplete adapter. But im getting the following error: Ive been sstuck on this for 2 days now :( so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

[cant pass mGeoDataClient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mclyS.png)

[The error i am recieving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4y7X.png)

Here is my MapClass:

```
    import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceDetectionClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    protected GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;
    private PlaceDetectionClient mPlaceDetectionClient;

    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-34.041458, 150.790100), new LatLng(-33.682247, 151.383362));

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if(mLocationPermissionGranted){
            init();
        }

    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //widgets
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchText;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    private  PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mplaceAutocompleteAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        mSearchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        getLocationPermission();
    }


    private void init(){
        mPlaceDetectionClient = Places.getPlaceDetectionClient(this);
        mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(this);

        mSearchText.setAdapter(mplaceAutocompleteAdapter);

        Log.d(TAG, "init: initializing");

        mplaceAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, mGeoDataClient, BOUNDS_GREATER_SYDNEY, null);
        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    //execute our method for searching
                    geoLocate();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");
        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }

        if(list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: found a location: " + address.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom){

        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving te camera to: lat"  + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

    }
    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: Initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "GetLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                initMap();
            }else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult: called");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult: permission failed ");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult: permission failed ");
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    //initialize our map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my app build gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tw276.ghkjhk"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0 '
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'


    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'


    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and here is my adapter class:

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;


/**
 * Adapter that handles Autocomplete requests from the Places Geo Data Client.
 * {@link AutocompletePrediction} results from the API are frozen and stored directly in this
 * adapter. (See {@link AutocompletePrediction#freeze()}.)
 */
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutocomplete";
    private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    /**
     * Current results returned by this adapter.
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;

    /**
     * Handles autocomplete requests.
     */
    private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;

    /**
     * The bounds used for Places Geo Data autocomplete API requests.
     */
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;

    /**
     * The autocomplete filter used to restrict queries to a specific set of place types.
     */
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

    /**
     * Initializes with a resource for text rows and autocomplete query bounds.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int)
     */
    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GeoDataClient geoDataClient,
                                    LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
        mGeoDataClient = geoDataClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
     */
    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of results received in the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an item from the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Sets the primary and secondary text for a row.
        // Note that getPrimaryText() and getSecondaryText() return a CharSequence that may contain
        // styling based on the given CharacterStyle.

        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
        textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(STYLE_BOLD));

        return row;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the filter for the current set of autocomplete results.
     */
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                // We need a separate list to store the results, since
                // this is run asynchronously.
                ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    filterData = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                }

                results.values = filterData;
                if (filterData != null) {
                    results.count = filterData.size();
                } else {
                    results.count = 0;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    mResultList = (ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                // when clicked.
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Submits an autocomplete query to the Places Geo Data Autocomplete API.
     * Results are returned as frozen AutocompletePrediction objects, ready to be cached.
     * Returns an empty list if no results were found.
     * Returns null if the API client is not available or the query did not complete
     * successfully.
     * This method MUST be called off the main UI thread, as it will block until data is returned
     * from the API, which may include a network request.
     *
     * @param constraint Autocomplete query string
     * @return Results from the autocomplete API or null if the query was not successful.
     * @see GeoDataClient#getAutocompletePredictions(String, LatLngBounds, AutocompleteFilter)
     * @see AutocompletePrediction#freeze()
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.
        Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results =
                mGeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(constraint.toString(), mBounds,
                        mPlaceFilter);

        // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most
        // 60s for a result from the API.
        try {
            Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse autocompletePredictions = results.getResult();

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");

            // Freeze the results immutable representation that can be stored safely.
            return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
        } catch (RuntimeExecutionException e) {
            // If the query did not complete successfully return null
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact `class` the `PlaceAutocompleteAdapter` constructor expects is

```
com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient
```

While you're importing, erroneously

```
com.google.android.libraries.places.compat.GeoDataClient
```

inside your `MapActivity` class

Comment: I changed the library, but then i get the error: 

mGeoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(this); 

Incompatible types.
Required:
com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient
Found:
com.google.android.libraries.places.compat.GeoDataClient

Comment: Thanks for the help LppEdd

Comment: @Tman You need to use **everywhere** `com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient`

Comment: Thanks @LppEdd. I have changed the import in MapActivity and the PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.class. yet I still get the new error? on the plus side the original error has gone haha. I cant find anywhere else that i have importing the wrong client.

Comment: Error has gone! Thanks LppEdd that has been stressing me out for days haha

Although, my autocomplete is not working, no suggestions :( would you mind looking at my code to see if you can spot anything? Il edit the code now :)

Comment: @Tman unfortunately I'm not an Android developer, so I don't know how these API works

Comment: Thanks for all your help LppEdd

Comment: @Tman it's nothing. Remember to tackle these errors most of the time reading the documentation is sufficient.